# Python Undetected_Chrome driver issue

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am getting this error with python undetected chrome driver library

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 driver=init_browser(False)`your text`
      2 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
      3 def login(driver):

Cell In[7], line 9
      7     options.add_argument('--headless')
      8 options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
----> 9 driver = Chrome(options=options)
     10 driver.maximize_window()
     11 return driver

File c:\Users\alphaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py:258, in Chrome.__init__(self, options, user_data_dir, driver_executable_path, browser_executable_path, port, enable_cdp_events, desired_capabilities, advanced_elements, keep_alive, log_level, headless, version_main, patcher_force_close, suppress_welcome, use_subprocess, debug, no_sandbox, user_multi_procs, **kw)
    251 self.patcher = Patcher(
    252     executable_path=driver_executable_path,
    253     force=patcher_force_close,
    254     version_main=version_main,
    255     user_multi_procs=user_multi_procs,
    256 )
    257 # self.patcher.auto(user_multiprocess = user_multi_num_procs)
--> 258 self.patcher.auto()
    260 # self.patcher = patcher
    261 if not options:
...
File c:\Users\alphaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py:639, in HTTPDefaultErrorHandler.http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    638 def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 639     raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

script was working before.
need help

please guide to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on a previously working script. I updated the python package with pip using `pip install undetected-chromedriver -U` and it worked again after.